# Get time taken for specific build step in TeamCity

Tags: time, teamcity

We are running TeamCity8 and wondered is there any way to access the time a specific build step has taken?

Cheers for any suggestions.

Duncan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available via a REST call:
http://[server_name]/app/rest/builds/id:[build_id]/statistics

Here's a sample response:

```
<properties count="36">
<property name="ArtifactsSize" value="1274836"/>
<property name="BuildArtifactsPublishingTime" value="97"/>
<property name="BuildCheckoutTime" value="1480093"/>
<property name="BuildDuration" value="7324057"/>
<property name="BuildDurationNetTime" value="5843867"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:artifactsPublishing" value="107"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:buildFinishing" value="3"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_107" value="20868"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_11" value="107"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_13" value="334"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_14" value="3671"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:firstStepPreparation" value="113"/>
<property name="buildStageDuration:sourcesUpdate" value="1480310"/>
<property name="BuildTestStatus" value="1"/>
<property name="InspectionStatsE" value="0.000000"/>
<property name="InspectionStatsW" value="0.000000"/>
<property name="PassedTestCount" value="24"/>
<property name="SampleStatistics" value="1"/>
<property name="SuccessRate" value="1"/>
<property name="TimeSpentInQueue" value="154"/>
<property name="TotalTestCount" value="24"/>
<property name="VisibleArtifactsSize" value="1266844"/>
</properties>
```

If perhaps you want to send this as metrics to Graphite, try the wonderful [TeamCity Graphite plugin](https://github.com/mendhak/teamcity-graphite) that basically makes use of this data as well (though it gets the data directly from the TeamCity OpenAPI rather than using REST calls).

The only disadvantage (of both the above) is that you need to decode the cryptic step names (e.g. `"buildStepRUNNER_107"`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can get some data back (for a given build id) but the values don't seem to match what is in the build log. For example, the step in the build log say it took 1h 2 mins but the corresponding step here (assuming it's in milliseconds) equates to about 42 mins.

Comment: I've seen that, and reported it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-40798). JetBrains have marked it as duplicate of [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21551), which they claim to have fixed in 9.1. What version of TC are you using?

Comment: we are using 8.1.5 so perhaps I need to bring forward out upgrade :). Cheers for the info and help.